# how do I add a caption to the photo

Tags: html, css

[image: what i want to happen]

```css
#title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #643F37;
  font-family: Arial;
}

h3 {
  margin-left: 700px;
  color: #643F37;
  font-family: arial;
}

.image {
  hight: 1000px;
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  postion: relative;
}

#main {
  background: hsl(0, 1%, 90%);
  font-family: times new roman;
  font-size: 40px;
  align-items: center;
}

#img-div {
  #
}

#img-caption .image {
  position: relative;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <h1 id="title">
    The story of Clarnece Jordan
  </h1>
  <h3>
    by clarence
  </h3>
</head>

<body>
  <main id="main">
    <div id="img-div">
      <img class="image" src="https://scontent-dfw5-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/69294192_733858860396587_3589774459596177408_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=174925&_nc_ohc=vp-El7mg4WAAX_k529k&_nc_ht=scontent-dfw5-2.xx&oh=da307ba4e9977da7860d2dc87e333e85&oe=60926139">
    </div>
    <div id="img-caption">
      <p> this is a picture is form church
        <p>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you trying to center the caption below the photo?

Answer (score 0):

You have to understant first the usage of html objects, I'd recommend you to take first a quick tutorial and be aware of the typos, this will make your development much easier. For your problem...

This site may help you with your specific problem: https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_figcaption.asp

This page is extremely useful for begginers and has a lot of tutorials.

Also I'd suggest to use classes instead of id's and make them reusable; for example:

```css
.text-center {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .title {
        text-align: center;
        color: #643F37;
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    .subtitle {
        color: #643F37;
        font-family: arial;
    }

    .image {
        height: 1000px;
        width: auto;
        display: block;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }

    .main {
        background: hsl(0, 1%, 90%);
        font-family: times new roman;
        font-size: 40px;
        align-items: center;
    }

    figcaption {
        font-style: italic;
        padding: 2px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Clarnece Jordan</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">

        <h1 class="title text-center">The story of Clarnece Jordan </h1>
        <h3 class="text-center subtitle">by clarence</h3>

        <div>
            <img class="image" src="https://scontent-dfw5-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/69294192_733858860396587_3589774459596177408_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=174925&_nc_ohc=vp-El7mg4WAAX_k529k&_nc_ht=scontent-dfw5-2.xx&oh=da307ba4e9977da7860d2dc87e333e85&oe=60926139">
            <figcaption>This is a picture is form church</figcaption>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This site might be helpful:  https://www.lifewire.com/caption-that-stays-with-image-3467838 .

Steps to an HTML Image Caption

1. Add an image to your webpage.
2. In the HTML for your webpage, place a div tag around the image:
3. Add a style attribute to the div tag:
4. Set the width of the div to the same width as the image, with the width style property:

Comment: What about if you want to put it on the picture not under it?